# Just installed Postgresql and unable to do anything in the console

Tags: postgresql

Whenever I try anything I get this message:

Can't locate warnings.pm:   /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30.0/warnings.pm: Permission denied at /usr/bin/psql line 19.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/psql line 19.

The usr directory doesn't exist after installation.

I've tried removing Postgresql several times and reinstalling with the same results. I want to learn how to use it but can't get past this installation problem.

I'm running Linux Mint 20.3

Comment: Are you saying that installing PostgreSQL caused '/usr/' to disappear from the filesystem?

Comment: No, there is no x86_64... directory.

Comment: My mistake. I was looking in the /bin folder.  The directory structure does indeed exist.  The warnings.pm doesn't exist however.

Comment: Not near enough information, need: 1) Postgres version? 2) How did you install Postgres? 3) What is the command you are running that caused the error? **Add answers as update to question**.

Comment: psql in ubuntu (and so I assume mint as well) is a wrapper, written in Perl, around the real psql.  And it seems like your Perl installation is broken.  Maybe you can try reinstalling Perl in an attempt to fix it.  You could search for the real `psql` binary and run that, but ignoring the brokenness of a system component seems like a bad idea.

Comment: I'm installing Postgres from the website (https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/), with the latest version according to the page. The instructions and commands are on the page, which I used. The first thing I wanted to do was add a user.  But it doesn't matter what I try to do I get that error message.  I found another Warnings.pm file in another Perl folder and copied it but it doesn't seem to know it's there.  My Perl installations seems ok and not broken.